# How to apply calculation on a dataframe for each unique ID(multiple similar ID's in a column)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with

| ID | Subset | Start | End | New Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 6 |  |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 9 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 7 |  |
| 3 | 1 | 19 | 12 |  |

I want to make a new column with the difference of shift(-1) start and end which would apply to each ID and subset. The new column will give the difference between start and end for each ID and subset.

The output should look like this:
New column will have difference of starting and end points of same ID and subset. Otherwise it should be Nan.

| ID | Subset | Start | End | New Col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 9 | Nan |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 12 | NaN |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 4 | Nan |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 7 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 9 | 12 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 13 | 14 | Nan |

I tried:

```
df['New Col'] = df['Start'].shift(-1) - df['End']
```

But couldn't find a way of doing this for each unique ID and subset.

Comment: The Start/End dates of your output don't match the input - is this intended?

Comment: Yes, It is starting point and ending point, so the new column would show 7-6 = 1. For ID and subset where there is no another starting point it would should Nan.

Comment: `df.groupby(['ID', 'Subset'])['Start'].shift(-1) - df['End']`?

Comment: @QuangHoang That's what I thought, but his output data doesn't match - I'm guessing it's a typo

Comment: It worked, thanks